# Non-consistent hibernate dialect error, goes away with ipconfig /renew

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, c3p0

It's my first question here. I'll try to be as specific as possible.

First of all, I know there are a lot of topics regarding this error, some with solutions, **but my case is different because I have this error not every time and it goes away for some time after I type ipconfig /renew in cmd**. So, now to detail.

I work in Windows 7.

This is my datasource config:

```
package ...;

import ...;

@Configuration
public class DataSourceConfig {

  @Value("${db.url}") private String url;
  @Value("${db.user}") private String user;
  @Value("${db.pass}") private String pass;
  @Value("${db.poolSize.init}") private int initPoolSize;
  @Value("${db.poolSize.min}") private int minPoolSize;
  @Value("${db.poolSize.max}") private int maxPoolSize;
  @Value("${db.statements.max}") private int maxStatements;
  @Value("${db.idleTime.max}") private int maxIdleTime;
  @Value("${db.checkoutTimeout}") private int checkoutTimeout;

 @Bean
  public DataSource oracleDataSource() throws SQLException {
    ComboPooledDataSource dataSource = new ComboPooledDataSource();
    dataSource.setJdbcUrl(url);
    dataSource.setUser(user);
    dataSource.setPassword(pass);
    dataSource.setInitialPoolSize(initPoolSize);
    dataSource.setMaxPoolSize(maxPoolSize);
    dataSource.setMinPoolSize(minPoolSize);
    dataSource.setMaxIdleTime(maxIdleTime);
    dataSource.setMaxStatements(maxStatements);
    dataSource.setCheckoutTimeout(checkoutTimeout);

    return dataSource;
  }
}
```

JPA config:

```
package ...;
import ...;

@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfig {

  @Autowired
  private DataSource dataSource;

  @Value("${is.ddl.enabled}")
  private String isDDLenabled ;

  @Bean
  public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory() {

    HibernateJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(Boolean.valueOf(isDDLenabled));

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
    factory.setPackagesToScan("...");
    factory.setDataSource(dataSource);
    factory.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
  }


  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager Here() {
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
    return transactionManager;
  }
}
```

I run in with Jetty. **When I run it for the first several times, it's ok**. But after 8-15 runs I get the following:

```
Failed startup of context ...
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
...
org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory]: Factory method 'entityManagerFactory' threw exception; nested exception is org.hibernate.HibernateException: Access to DialectResolutionInfo cannot be null when 'hibernate.dialect' not set
```

And after that if I try to run the project I get the same error **until I run ipconfig /renew command** in the command line. After that it runs again without problem for another 8-15 times.

Have anyone here encountered anything like this? How can ipconfig affect the running of the project like this? Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter` you should use this `org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect`

```
HibernateJpaDialect hibernateJpaDialect =new HibernateJpaDialect();
```

And set factory object as below:

```
factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(hibernateJpaDialect);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Rohit-Gaikwad. However, .setJpaVendorAdapter() does not accept HibernateDialect as a parameter. It accepts HibernateJpaVendorAdapter. And I already set it. Besides, I use .setJpaDialect(new HibernateDialect()). So, what exactly do I need to change in this situation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, see above. Thanks anyway.

Comment: So, @Rohit Gaikwad , can we continue? Are there any thoughts taking into account what I've answered to you?

Comment: as setJpaVendorAdapter() does not accepts HibernateDialect as a parameter, i'm looking for another method to set HibernateDialect. method like "setJpaAdapter.." or "setJpaVendorAdapter..." Or any other thing instead of vendor specific dialect.

Comment: There is a method setJpaDialect. It does accept HibernateJpaDialect as a parameter and I use it. Isn't it what you're looking for?

Comment: yes i know that, we need to look into the exception msg "'here, hibernate.dialect' is not set" . If any how we set this property correctly this would solve the issue.

Comment: The important part there is that this exception occurs only after about ten successful runs. And goes away after ipconfig /renew command. Do you have any idea how can this exception be connected to ipconfig?

Comment: Please add the code using which you are initializing configuration, serviceRegistry, and sessionFactory.

Comment: I think when we do not specify hibernate.dialect then hibernate tries to use built-in dialects. now when your jars are not localized (say you are using maven) then hb will retry to get this jars from maven repo, but once the ip is changed, may be there occurs an ip conflict issue. I'm not good in networking, that's why i'm trying to set the  hibernate.dialect in the program code.

Comment: In fact, I don't use neither ServiceRegistry, nor SessionFactory. Yes, I know people fix their persistent hibernate dialect error with configuring SessionFactory in a certain order. But I have other issue. Mine is not constant and without SessionFactory.

Comment: I did set the dialect in code. Just like that: factory.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());